# RAILS 6 - How to update a HAS_MANY THROUGH table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Lets say I habe this pupolar basic example:

[image]

With the migrations:

```
class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :physicians do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
     end

  create_table :patients do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.timestamps
  end

  create_table :appointments do |t|
    t.belongs_to :physician
    t.belongs_to :patient
    t.datetime :appointment_date
    t.timestamps
  end
end
end
```

My only question is here, what would the command to create a new relation between physican and patient but do also update the **appointment_date field in the "appointments"** table ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways.

1) Via Physician instance

Assuming you have `physician` and `patient` instance

`physician.appointments.create(patient: patient, appointment_date: <INSERT DATE HERE>)`

2) Via Patient instance

same as 1 but the association flips

Assuming you have `physician` and `patient` instance

`patient.appointments.create(physician: physician, appointment_date: <INSERT DATE HERE>)`

3) Using Appointment model

same as 1 but the association flips

Assuming you have `physician` and `patient` instance

`Appointment.create(physician: physician, patient: patient, appointment_date: <INSERT DATE HERE>)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily like below. I guess you already have physician and patient in database -

```
@physycian  = Physician.last
@patient    = Patient.last
@physycian.appointments.create(patient_id: @patient.id, appointment_date: Time.current )
```

Also can be done using patient

```
@patient.appointments.create(physycian_id: @physycian.id, appointment_date: Time.current )
```